# How to show that $1+ \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \frac {x^n} n$ converges pointwise?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble showing that the taylor series for $-\ln(1-x)$ converges pointwise on $[0,1)$.

I have that the $k$ derivative is $\dfrac {(k-1)!} {(1-x)^k}$. This gives that the Taylor series with $k$ terms (or $k+1$ terms if you include the $0$) is $1+ \sum \limits _{n=1} ^k \dfrac {x^n} n$.

We obviously have convergence at $0$. But let $x \in (0,1)$. Then the Lagrange Remainder says that the error after taking $k$ terms is $\left|\dfrac {f ^{k+1} (c) x^{k+1} } {(k+1)!} \right|$, where $c \in (0,x)$. This is: $\left| \dfrac {x^{k+1}} {(1-c)^{k+1} (k+1)} \right|$. But does this part need to go to zero as $k$ goes to infinity? An upper bound for this is $\left| \dfrac {x^{k+1}} {(1-x)^{k+1} k} \right|$. But this does not go to zero if $x > 0.5$. Is there a way to get a better bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to study the convergence set of the power series $\sum a_n x^n$, you have to study its [convergence radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence), which is given by $\dfrac 1 {\lim \sqrt[n] |a_n|}$ or, equivalently, by $\dfrac 1 {\lim \left| \frac { a_{n+1} } {a_n} \right|}$. For the series $1 + \sum \dfrac 1 n x^n$, you have $a_n = \dfrac 1 n$ and the radius is easily seen to be $1$.

How do we interpret this? If $r$ is the convergence radius, there is a theorem saying that your series:

- converges (even *absolutely*) for $|x| < r$ (even stronger: it converges absolutely and *uniformly* for $|x| \le r - \varepsilon$ for $0 < \varepsilon < r$);
- diverges for $|x| > r$;
- for $|x| = r$ you have to resort to other arguments, since this thereom fails to draw any conclusion.

Applying this to your problem, the theorem guarantees that the series converges (pointwisely) for $|x| < 1$, i.e. for $x \in (-1, 1)$ (not just on $[0,1)$ as you say). What happens in $\pm 1$? Well, if $x = 1$ then $\ln (1-x)$ explodes; if $x = -1$ then use [Leibnitz's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) on the alternating series $1 + \sum \dfrac 1 n (-1)^n$ to show that it converges. We conclude that your Taylor series converges pointwisely on $[-1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, I guess we also need to show that it converges pointwise to the given function $-ln(1-x)$, but I think that follows easily by differnetiation and integration of the power series. Thank you for your help. I had forgotten about these techniques, so in some cases it is not possible to handle the Taylor series without the theory for power-series?

Comment: @user119615: In order to establish the convergence set, yes, you need to resort to power series. Once you do this, Taylor's theorem essentially does the rest, guaranteeing that the Taylor series of $f$ converges pointwisely to $f$, no need to differentiate or integrate the series anymore.

Comment: Thank you, but does Taylors theorem guarantee that if we have convergence we have convergence to the correct f? I think I have heard about Taylor-series that converges, but not to the function we started with.

Comment: @user119615: If the function that you started with is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), then yes, its Taylor series converges to it. If the function is not analytic (but still infinitely derivable), then either its Taylor series does not converge (you can check this by computing its convergence radius), or it converges (on some set) but not to the function itself.